# Flutter API calls on android device are not working

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am developing an app with flutter. API calls on android device is not working.

API calls working fine with iOS and android simulators and iPhone, but not working with android real devices.

I have added the permission too

```
android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

[image]

I am getting the following error

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: SocketException: Connection failed (OS Error: Network is unreachable, errno = 101), address = fidhappy.com, port = 443
```

[image]

But if i turn on wifi on android device. the api calls are working. its not working with mobile data.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Could you check if you can open `fidhappy.com` in the browser of your phone when using **mobile data**?

Comment: yes it works i will attach the screenshot. It doesn't work on one phone but works on another phone.

Comment: https://i.diawi.com/sRce7G check this app. it just static app. click on login and goto subscription or settings -> currency. i tested in three phones. it works in two phones and one phone not working. so it must be phone issue right?

Comment: Yes, I think so. Maybe try to restart the device and/or clear its caches, or factory reset if the others don't help.

Comment: okay i will try restart the device. thank you

Comment: did you get any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

If the endpoint is reachable through wifi but not using mobile data, you'll need to check if the network service provider blocks the endpoint that you're using. You might also want to consider testing on other devices to ensure that it's not a device specific issue.